# How to use Javascript object properties with Wasm module

Tags: webassembly

I would like to have example for importing property from javascript object to be get/set by Wasm module.

What kind of import should i use? (Function, Table, Memory OR Global).

For example i want to read `Date.length` property from Wasm.

Comment: Do you use any languages? Or just pure Wasm?

Comment: I can use examples of pure .wasm or .wat files. And I need importObject example for WebAssembly.instantiate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this (nor will you ever be able to do this) with pure WebAssembly. What systems like rust's wasm_bindgen do is have a function written in js which takes (object, value) and returns object[value].

```js
function getProperty(object, value) {
  return object[value];
}
```

```lisp
(module
  (import "host" "getProperty" (func $getProperty (param anyref) (param anyref) (result anyref))
)
```

For setting a property, you'd have an (object, property, value) function.

Comment: That's what i thought. Thanks